# Documentation feature-request: Prevent duplicate topics server-side

Tags: feature-request, documentation

There are several feature requests already related to handling duplicate topics or making it easier to avoid them, but I have a more Draconian request: I think that the app should make it impossible (going forward) to create duplicates.

I obviously have no idea what the app looks like internally, but I imagine it like this: if a user enters a topic name for an area that already exists, the app simply stops and in a flash says "There's already a topic with that name. Would you like to edit that topic?" I'm guessing that topic names are stored per-area (e.g. under Java, there are apparently three topics named "immutable object"; I first noticed this because under Lua, there are two topics named "Metatables"). So it shouldn't be too hard to check *before* a new topic is saved.

The advantage here, in my opinion, is that it removes the need for a lot of social management and cleanup by making a human error impossible. (Think of it like an email field that refuses to accept what looks like an invalid address because, say, a user forgets to type the `@gmail.com` portion of their email.)

Comment: Same should apply to examples.